# Convert normal list into multi column DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a simple list of floats like this (length is much larger, and it is always multiplies of **3**):

```
InputList = (0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.8, 1.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9, 1.4, 1.1, 0.3)
```

Need to create a DataFrame, where the values in the first column are the first 4 elements of the list, the second column are the next 4 elements and so on.
Resulted DataFrame should has number of columns equal to **3** and looks like the following:

```
Index,   Col1,   Col2,   Col3
0,       0.5,    1.2,    0.9
1,       0.3,    0.5,    1.4
2,       0.2,    0.6,    1.1
3,       0.8,    0.7,    0.3
```

I appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 2):

Create numpy array, so possible use [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), `-1` is for dynamic count shape from array:

```
InputList = (0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.8, 1.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9, 1.4, 1.1, 0.3)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(InputList).reshape(-1, 3, order='F'), 
                  columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3'])
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0   0.5   1.2   0.9
1   0.3   0.5   1.4
2   0.2   0.6   1.1
3   0.8   0.7   0.3
```

Comment: Thank you - it solved the problem! So fast, short and efficient solution :-)